# Converting my class to accept generic response Type, swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

The code below builds successfully

```
class mNoxHttpClient {

    var apiUrl      : String = ""
    var operation   : Int = -1
    var postData    : AnyObject

    var responseData : Forecast?

    init (apiUrl:String, operation:Int, postData:AnyObject) {
        self.apiUrl         = apiUrl
        self.operation      = operation
        self.postData       = postData
    }

    func doInBackground() {
        let fullURL = God.getFullURL(apiURL: self.apiUrl)
        Alamofire.request(fullURL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Forecast>) in
                self.responseData = response.result.value!
        }
    }

    func doAfterBackgroundCompletes() {
        assert(false, "This method must be overriden by the subclass")
    }

    //
    // Run background task
    //
    func execute() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
           self.doInBackground()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.doAfterBackgroundCompletes()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I make the following changes

1. change the type of responseData to `var responseData AnyObject`
2. change the type within the Alamofire response to (response: DataResponse)

I get a

> Cannot convert value of type (DataResponse)->() to expected Argument type (DataResponse)->Void

The need is for the derived class to `typecast` responseData to their own type at runtime.

How can I achieve this ?

**EDIT**

I modified my code to look like this. Basically I gave up on responseObject, and am now trying to use responseJSON. I'll use a objectmapper for converting the json to a swift pojo.

```
var responseData : Any? {
    get {
        return self.responseData
    }
    set {
        self.responseData = newValue
    }
}

func doInBackground() {
        //
        // This method will send the request, and make the response ready
        //
        let fullURL = God.getFullURL(apiURL: self.apiUrl)
        Alamofire.request(fullURL).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey found anything regarding this., like creating a generic class for handling all api response..

Comment: Not really.. still waiting for someone smart to fix this issue for me..

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Not as yet, still looking for a solution.